# proper activation function at output and loss function to optimize for OCR?

Tags: computer-vision, ocr, loss-function, multiclass-classification, activation-function

I am trying to make a CNN model on [IAM handwritten words data](http://www.fki.inf.unibe.ch/databases/iam-handwriting-database)(which has images of words handwritten by multiple people and targets are text in the images). So, I can encode words to numbers(A=0, B=1 and so on for capital, small and punctuation). But, I couldn't quite decide on what loss to use for this problem, in `tensforflow.keras`.

I have found out about something called CTC loss on some repositories on GitHub. But, ctc loss was used with softmax as activation in final dense layer. And since softmax outputs probabilities for each class that sum up to 1; So, I presume softmax can't output probabilties for two "*o*"s at the same time.

So, what are the proper activation and loss functions that I can use for a problem like this one?

Comment: the softmax is applied for each text position separately, so outputting two "o"s is no problem. In fact, CTC is well suited for text recognition, while your approach can't handle words which were not in the training set, while CTC is able to do this, as long as it has seen all the characters of the word. Here is a short intro I've written about CTC: https://towardsdatascience.com/3797e43a86c

Comment: For each position softmax will output the probability that letter belong to a class. So, since there will only be a neuron for each class, how will softmax output two separate probabilities for two "o"s. I still couldn't understand how this will happen. Thanks for the link to the article about loss function, i will read it.

Comment: there is one output per class (e.g. "a", "b", ...), but repeated T times, and the softmax is applied per time-step (so for each t in 1...T), so for each time-step, the character-probabilities sum to 1. For details see link, e.g. Fig. 3.

Comment: last doubt. What defines(or what should be) the number of time steps to make an RNN block with, for training?

Comment: thats somehow a trade-off between speed and ability to recognize long words, for an example, see: https://github.com/githubharald/SimpleHTR which has 32 time-steps, and is therefore well suited for word recognition, while it would be too small to read complete text lines.

Comment: Thanks for your time and detailed article and a github repo on the same data. that would be helpful for me.

Comment: @Harry, What ensures that softmax be applied for each class(repeated T times.) as you said in your previous comment; since usually, in case of multi-class classification (only which I know till now), after applying softmax to a layer, sum of all neuron's outputs in that layer will be equal to 1.